# PrimeReact and styled-component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, primereact

I can't seem to style a PrimeReact component with styled-component.

Given the below code to render an InputText, my intention is to change the width of it.  But it doesn't work.

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import {InputText} from 'primereact/components/inputtext/InputText';

class Component extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <InputText/>
        )
}

const ComponentView = styled(Component)`
    .ui-inputtext {
        width: 1000px;
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`styled-components` generates a `className` that should be passed to the component.

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import {InputText} from 'primereact/components/inputtext/InputText';

class Component extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <InputText className={this.props.className} /> <---- here
        )
}

const ComponentView = styled(Component)`
    .ui-inputtext {
        width: 1000px;
    }
`;
```

If `InputText` doesn't accept `className`, you can simply wrap it with another component:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import {InputText} from 'primereact/components/inputtext/InputText';

class Component extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.className}> <---- here
                <InputText />
            </div>
        )
}

const ComponentView = styled(Component)`
    .ui-inputtext {
        width: 1000px;
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

PrimeReact has a lot of styles applied with a separate sass stylesheet, often combining multiple classnames and html tags.

To get your styles to win, you need more CSS specificity.

A solution is to use a nested selector, like:

```
const ComponentView = styled(Component)`
&&& {
    width: 1000px;
}`
```

This will generate 3 identical classnames and is recommended by the [Styled Components docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity). More classname specificity needed? Use more `&`s.

Or you could put in a `!important`. I've seen this around.

Or edit [their sass file](https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/blob/master/src/sass/App.scss).